# Having the most fair cross-validation result

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, cross-validation, model-selection, supervised-learning

The question is about the stability of cross-validation technique in classification:

Assuming $K$-fold cross-validation ($K=10$, most common value). When we call the partitioning function, the samples of the 10 folds are randomly chosen from the giving data set. After cross-validation, we will get some value of the performance indicator (e.g. misclassification rate) $mcr_1$. Recalling the partitioning function ($K$ is always equals to 10), of course we will get another value, e.g. $mcr_2$ (since the samples of the folds are randomly selected).

Is it a good idea to repeat the $K$-fold cross-validation process $N$ times and then  consider the mean of $mcr_i$? On the other hand, this will make simulations for model selection too heavy.

If so, what can be a good value of $N$ in order to have a statistically significant mean? Are there another optimized idea, giving a stable or fair performance indicator for cross-validation technique?

Additional information: I'm working on Matlab.